# Battery dropping from 90% to 0%

Tags: cyanogenmod, battery, htc-desire

I've had the same device for quite some years now, and played a lot with it changing ROMs a few times. Recently I've been experiencing sudden drops in battery charge, here's a screenshot:

[image: battery usage]
<sup>Battery Usage (screenshot; click image for larger variant)</sup>

What could be the reason for this? Is the battery old and faulty and in need of a replacement? Or is the current ROM (Chromium ROM Build 11) faulty?

I am prepared to see a degradation in battery life after so many years, but I would expect the drop to be linear. Instead it is lasting quite long while in stand-by, and drops quickly when I use it, but no app appears to be draining it.

EDIT: I've tried resetting battery stats, it's of no use.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely the battery. It might have to be replaced. If it's literally dropping from 90 straight down to 0, then the battery health has reached its end. If you do replace the battery and the same thing occurs, it could be your ROM

Comment: Sometimes it drops at 90%, most ofter it drops around 50%, haven't seen it going below that for quite some time. I'm suspecting the ROM because when it's between 100% and 90%, and I connect the charger, it sometimes doesn't start charging.